# Send post data with file upload AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am currently sending a file via AJAX like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();

    //do stuff to that adds files

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Upload/' + ID);
    xhr.send(fd);
```

And using the file in my contoller like:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
```

This all works fine but I want to send more information. How can I post more variables along with the file?

Answer (score 1):

use variable name in `xhr.send()`. Like `xhr.send(var1=fd&var2=anotherdata)`.
Then at your server side create two POST data handlers, namely `var1` & `var2`. One will hold fd and other will hold extra data.

Comment: i would prefer not to change routing. I found another way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: oh...great...thanks for posting your way...that actually can be useful in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var fd = new FormData();

    //do stuff to that adds files
    fd.append("Variable1", "data");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Upload/' + ID);
    xhr.send(fd);
```

This worked best for me.